# Cordova Build failed with an exception

Tags: cordova

When I Try To Build Android With Cordova, It's Show below error, how can I fix it?

Windows 10

Cordova Version: 8.0.0

JDK: 1.8.0

Gradle Version: 4.4

SDK Is Full (All Android Versions)

```
F:\Projects\Cordova\board>cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=E:\SDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\Projects\Cordova\board\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
      > com/android/builder/core/ErrorReporter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:10900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\Projects\Cordova\board\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
      > com/android/builder/core/ErrorReporter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:10900) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.
This Problem Solved By Install Android Studio And Build A Project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal in your project folder, remove and add the android platform.

```
1. cordova platform rm android
2. cordova platform add android
```